# StackOverflowError exception. Cannot evaluate org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.toString()

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

`ElasticSearchTemplate` throws exception during initialization `Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.toString()`.

**XML config**

```
<elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-nodes="localhost:9300" />

<bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client"/>
</bean>
```

Does anyone know whats causing this issue. `Elastic` version `5.6.3 and 5.5.0` and `Spring Data Elastic 3.0.1` and Not using `SpringBoot`

Now using: [Elastic High Level Rest Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-getting-started.html)

Comment: I am having the same error with elasticsearch 6.2 and I am using transport client.

Comment: Same here with version 5.6.3

Comment: I am using 6.3 with transport client. I met the same problem.

Comment: I have given up on it and now using HghLevelRestClient

Comment: When Running With Debugger i also got the same issue. but the client is creating and it haven't causes any issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

When Running With Debugger i also got the same issue. but the client is creating and it haven't causes any issues for me. more info is here

```
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cannot-evaluate-org-elasticsearch-common-inject-injectorimpl-tostring/156014/3
```